# Add a script before </body> only on a single component - vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm vuejs newbie, and I'm start to use the clearsale api for validations and want make a fingerprint catch for an validation, and need's  call a script funcion on page's bottom only in one vuejs component. This is the  script in question:

```
<script>
    (function(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) {
      a["CsdpObject"] = e;
      (a[e] =
        a[e] ||
        function() {
          (a[e].q = a[e].q || []).push(arguments);
        }),
        (a[e].l = 1 * new Date());
      (f = b.createElement(c)), (g = b.getElementsByTagName(c)[0]);
      f.async = 1;
      f.src = d;
      g.parentNode.insertBefore(f, g);
    })(window, document, "script", "//device.clearsale.com.br/p/fp.js", "csdp");
    csdp("app", "appKey");
    csdp("sessionid", "sessionID");
</script>
```

I called out of export default scope, but thei not recognize the `csdp` functions.

(p.s. sorry about my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put this inline script in your `public/index.html` file - but without the last 2 statements (where you call the `csdp` function). In your component then you will write

```
window.csdp("app", "appKey");
window.csdp("sessionid", "sessionID");
```